# essential supremum and supremum for stochastic processes.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

For a continuous, right-continuous  or left-continuous process $Y$ we have that
$$\sup_{t\in[0,T]}Y_t = \operatorname*{ess sup}_{t\in[0,T]}Y_t = \operatorname*{ess sup}_{\tau\in\mathcal{T}_{0,T}} Y_t.$$
where $\mathcal{T}_{0,T}$ is the set of all stopping times $\tau$ such that $0\leq \tau \leq T$ a.s.

My question is: is this relation  still hold if $Y$ is just an optional làdlàg (right and left limited) process ?

Comment: Thank you saz and JGWang for your answer and comments.
Excuse me to ask you again: 
if $X$ and $Y$ two optional  right- and left-limited processes, is this equivalent true : 
$Y_{\tau}=X_{\tau}$ for all stopping time $\tau$ <=>
$Y_{t}=X_{t}$     for all $t∈[0,T]$ a.s.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general this does not hold for processes with right- and left-limits.

Consider for instance $\Omega := (0,1)$ with the Lebesgue measure (restricted to $(0,1)$) and define

$$Y_t(\omega) := 1_{\{1\}}(t), \qquad \omega \in \Omega, t \geq 0.$$

Then $$\operatorname*{sup}_{t \in [0,2]} Y_t = 1 \neq 0= \operatorname*{ess sup}_{t \in [0,2]} Y_t.$$

Comment: Maybe $Y_t(\omega):=1_{\{t=\omega\}}(t,\omega)$, $\omega\in\Omega,t\in(0,1)$ is better.

Comment: @JGWang Better for what?

Comment: $Y_t(\omega)\ne Y_t(\omega')$, when $\omega\ne\omega'$.

Comment: @JGWang So...? Why is this "better"?

Comment: we can choose $Y _{t}(w)=1_{\{t=w\}}(t,w)$, and $Ω=IR$ !!